# appointment.Sensitivity EWS C#

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Hi I am trying to display all non sensitive appointments in EWS (I can get all appointments fine, but even with restricted permissions I can still see private appointments which I shouldn't be able to see!)

This is basically what I want to do:

```
       if ( appointment.Sensitivity  == "Normal")

    Console.WriteLine(appointment.Subject);
}
```

However I get operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Sensitivity' and 'String'

Can someone please advise?

Comment: When I run 

Console.WriteLine(appointment.Sensitivity);

In my foreach statement it returns either Private or Normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare it to the enum `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Sensitivity` rather than using `ToString()`

```
string message = appointment.Subject + " - " + appointment.Sensitivity;

if (appointment.Sensitivity == Sensitivity.Normal)
    Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string message = appointment.Subject + " - " + appointment.Sensitivity;

if (appointment.Sensitivity.ToString() == "Normal")
    Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Comment: Found out - hope this is of use to someone else in the future